# How do I create a group of textfields that have separate variables that they edit in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, variables, foreach, swiftui

I am creating a simple program that creates several textfields to edit in. I use this code to create them:

```swift
ForEach((1...textfields).reversed(), id: \.self){ _ in
    TextField("Type here:", text: $text)
}
```

The `textfields` variable is controlled by a couple of buttons earlier in the code, but the real issue is the "text" variable. The buttons add and remove textfields, but editing one edits them all, which is not what I want. So my question is, how do I create textfields that contain unique variables but can still be made from the `ForEach`(or similar) loop?

Comment: Please provide more code to be able to reproduce this issue easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Question

The task here is to organise some sort of storage for the `TextField`s values.

### Solution

#### Step 1

The storage can be organised using `@State` or `@Binding` modifier. As we need to have a number of `TextField`s here, an `Array` of `String`s could be a good choice for storage type. This can be written like:

```swift
@State var values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Note that we provide here initial values as empty strings. It is for example purpose only. You can use anything that you want or replace `@State` with `@Binding` if you need to specify the values from a parent view.

Note that `[String]` type will be automatically inferred by swift.

#### Step 2

Then, the values need to be converted into  `TextField`s in the view's body implementation. To do this, we modify your `ForEach` a little bit:

```swift
// iterating through the indices of the values
ForEach(values.indices, id: \.self) { index in    
    // using index to create binding to the value
    TextField("Type here:", text: $values[index])
}
```

### Result

And here is the final result that we have:

```swift
struct MultipleTextViews: View {
    @State var values: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(values.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            TextField("Type here:", text: $values[index])
        }
    }
}
```